# A program like "easy php" that start on windows startup. Apache + PHP + Mysql only for local computer

Tags: easyphp

I need a program that create a web-like environment (like easyphp does) but without requiring user interaction to start (easyphp requires you to press "start").

The most important part is that it doesn't expose apache over the web but it must be available only to 127.0.0.1 (lan is allowed too but not required).

It must work with php and mysql.

I can't configure an apache server correctly by myself because there are a lot of options and security things that I think I really don't know enough well to set it up by myself.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can do it with [wampserver](http://www.wampserver.com/en/index.php) by adding a shortcut to wampserver in the startup folder (Start Menu)
or using the "Windows service manager"

Comment: At the moment is doing exactly what I asked for, give me a bit to test a little more

Comment: WAMP is generally great for local server jobs and even more.

Comment: Yea, it worked like a charm, solved me a really big problem. Thanks!

Comment: While I prefer Wamp, I don't see why EasyPHP couldn't be automatically launched at startup.  See this post If your [MySQL / Apache don't load automatically when launching easyPHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35700282/easyphp-16-1-autostart-http-mysql/44759456#44759456), .