# EasyPHP 16.1 autostart http & mysql

Tags: mysql, easyphp

I'm so confused, because each time I run EasyPHP I need to go through dashboard to start http and mysql server. It's really annoying. Is there any way to set easyphp to start http and mysql automaticaly? Now it takes 10 clicks to run site instead of 3 clicks in 14.1. And really more time.

Answer (score 8):

Using version 17, I had the same problem, and found a simple workaround :

*Be sure to first back-up your .ini files if you have any doubt.*

- Open `run-devserver.ini`
- Search the `[StartRestartAllServers]` section, and copy the action it contains...
- ...at the end of the `[StartupAction]` section.

Setting the values in `eds.ini` did **not** change anything  (I tried values *"1", "true", "yes" and "Y"*)

For the record, those values are :

*Autostart_httpserver=

Autostart_dbserver=*

Maybe the .ini expects something else, like the full path or command ?

Anyway.  Now, it works perfectly.

Comment: To this day, every machine that I've installed EasyPHP on has needed this fix. Cheers!

Comment: May I report that actually the `run-devserver.ini` is a hidden file in the root folder of easyPHP? It took me several minutes to find it!! :D
Anyway it worked like charm...I have the latest version, since I downoaded it a couple weeks ago and the problem's still there!

Answer (score 1):

This problem has been fixed with the last version ([16.1.1](http://www.example.com/)).

Comment: I'm glad that EasyPHP are answering questions about their product on SO, but to say it has been fixed, link to www.example.com, and then change the functionality again in EasyPHP 17 so that autostart is again disabled, is not helpful.

Comment: Autostart works fine with [Devserver 17](http://www.easyphp.org). Check the settings.